# Please recommend a good philosophical book on entropy

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-physics

Can you recommend a good book on entropy?
I'm interested in one which balances well philosophy and physics, since at both edges the likelihood of having to read through nonsense increases (physicists who don't appreciate philosophy or philosophers who don't know physics).

Comment: I can't recommend you a book myself, but I think you'll get better answers if you specify your current level and what topics you'd like the book to cover.

Comment: I think that it is still valuable : [Hans Reichenbach](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reichenbach/), [The Direction of Time](https://books.google.it/books?id=qjTrZ2vuQ9sC&pg=PA1) (ed or 1956 - Dover reprint).

Comment: To the questioner....ah...may be I must thank you for your personal request. However, due to the lack of my knowledge **regarding the PHILOSOPHICAL BOOK WITH ENTROPY**, I can not answer to you with sorry. My friend may know so I try to ask. Only what I can say right now is connecting entropy ( it is just a physic term ) with the philosophical issue or social science needs really cautious move according my acquaintance. Thank you. See also [this on Wiener entropy](http://soundanalysispro.com/manual-1/chapter-4-the-song-features-of-sap2/wiener-entropy).

Comment: Well...thank you, stocfury. I need to be silent if I am not **completely sure** about the questioner's question. Thank you.

Comment: For your further info, please refer http://www.isss.org/lumwiener.htm **Wiener's interests were not limited to logic, mathematics, cybernetics or mathematical physics. He was also familiar with all the aspects of philosophy, from epistemology and metaphysics to morals. . With The Human Use of Human Beings (1950) he gives a presentation of cybernetics underlining its social aspects with some emphasis on the role of randomness and entropy.**

Comment: He sure wrote about entropy relating with social system. Entropy, actually related with probability and its position according with its time, aaaaaaand I am sorry I forgot which book I referred to. But he surely is the one of the answers to your question.

Comment: In The Human Use of Human Beings ( in my language, it is translated as "Man A Machine", ughhhh, how come does it happen. ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Use_of_Human_Beings he seems to be describing the entropy with the **negantropy** stuff. ( I don't remember, sorry ). His main view was, if my recollection is correct, human beings are like radars which at that time relating with the development of the war time devices, like through the nerves on the fingers the information is made in human brain. The **feedback**, in the above link. I apologize if I am only messing here.

Comment: I recommend Richard Feynman, Lecture notes in Computation, Chap 5: Thermodynamics of Computation, because it shows intriguing links between information and entropy...

Comment: A good overview at an introductory level can be found in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, it is called "Thermodynamic Asymmetry in Time": http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time-thermo/

Answer (score 3):

There is an interesting book called "A Farewell to Entropy" by Arieh Ben-Naim, in which he shows how the thermodynamic concept of entropy can be reduced to information theory. Just as statistical mechanics underpins classical thermodynamics and shows how the bulk properties of matter can be explained in terms of the properties of ensembles of micro particles, so statistical mechanics is itself underpinned by information theory. Ben-Naim proposes replacing our understanding of entropy as disorder with entropy as lack of information.

This might be of philosophical interest, because it may help to clarify the relationship between information and epistemic probability on the one hand, and the laws of nature and physical propensities on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 9 of Hawking's "A Brief History of Time" has an interesting discussion of entropy.

Also the following "The Blackwell Guide to the Philosophy of Computing and Information" 
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0631229191.html

Has some good discussions of the philosophical aspects of entropy (and the physics of information) when seen from a information point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *Greene, Brian: The Fabric of the Cosmos. 2004*

The author starts with entropy in Chapter 6 "Chance and the Arrow. Does Time Have a Direction?". He follows the notion of entropy to cosmology and often comes back to the question, why the cosmos started with a state of low energy.

I must confess that I did not yet finish the book and that I did not follow each argumentation. But the book seems worthwile to learn how the notion of entropy embedds into the whole of cosmology.

The author is a physicist. He has the ability to pick up his readers on a popular level and then go ahead to the physical theory. One can always rely that he is familiar with the contemporary physic's background of his statements. Therefore I prefer this book to enter into the notion of entropy in its full range.

Concerning the philosophical aspect, I think each reader has to decide by himself whether the book gives him enough information to answer his personal philosophical questions concerning entropy. I recommend to start with a sound base from physics before discussing entropy from the view point of philosophy of nature.